# How to check if line has match when I search something and catch the linenumber?

Tags: search, vim, match, buffer, lines

I want to catch all linenumbers in the buffer with 1 or more matches.

Till now I used this code:

```
let lines = []

for line in range(startline, endline)
  let @e = ''
  :redir @e
  :silent exe line.'s/'.mysearch.'/&/gne'
  :redir END
  if matchstr(@e, 'match') != ''
    let nummer = matchstr(@e, '\d\+\ze')
    if nummer > 0
      call add(lines, ''.line.'')
    endif
  endif
endfor
```

But this is incredible slow.
Is there no way to do this faster?
(p.e. execute search silently: 1 for match and catch the linenumber and 0 for no match)

Comment: Can you formulate what are you trying to do exactly with that code ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス, Hi Meninx.. I want to catch all line numbers in my buffer with matches from a search... p.e. search is `exe 1s/foo/&/gne` if there is 'foo' in line 1, it gives a match and I want to put line 1 in my list `lines`. If there is no 'foo' in line 1 nothing has to be inserted in lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `filter()` on `getline(1,'$')`. To obtain line numbers instead we could play with `map()` and the new (Vim 8) lambdas. Or may be simply `filter (range (1, line ('$')), 'getline (v:val) =~ regex')`

You will hardly find anything faster with vim, especially manual loops.

EDIT:

For instance, searching `"home"` on a 7850 lines long vim log file where it occurs 6438 times:

- `echo lh#time#bench('filter', range (1, line ('$')), 'getline (v:val) =~ "home"')` takes 0.033297s
- `:echo lh#time#bench('filter', range (1, line ('$')),{ idx, val -> getline (val) =~ 'home'})[1]` takes 0.078506s -- a little bit slower, but the regex is simpler
- `let r=[]` + `echo = lh#time#bench('map', range(1, line('$')), 'substitute(getline(v:val), "home", "\\=add(g:r, v:val)", "")')[1]` takes 8.841528s -- I guess this is the kind of result you have with a manual loop
- `:let start=reltime()|:let lines=filter(map(getline(1, '$'), {idx, val -> val =~ "home"?idx:0}), "v:val>0")|:echo reltimefloat(reltime(start, reltime()))` takes: 0.075132s

BTW, I've also measured on the previous snippets, on my vim 8.0-134, that `match()` is a little bit (not really perceptible) slower than plain old `=~`. Don't ask me why.

IOW, cryptic regexes seems to be the fastest solution, and manual loops shall be avoided at all cost when performances matter.

Comment: Thanks Luc. `filter (range (1, line ('$')), 'getline (v:val) =~ regex')`  --> not an editor command. It seems not to be an editor command. Did I do something wrong? Regex must be the searchterm isn't it?

Comment: Use `matchstr()`.

Comment: Found it. Just had to assign it (linenrs = ). This is a great solution! The only problem I've found is that I often use single and double quotes in my regex. It is conflicting with the quotes you're using.

Comment: If you hardcode the regular expression in filter or map, you'll have to fight with double quotes. Instead you can store the expression into a variable. Or you can also use the new lambda feature from vim 8.

Comment: In doubt, `:h filter()`, `:h map()`, `:h lambda` (IIRC)

Comment: @LucHermitte, I checked the new lambda feature. It has nothing to do with the python lambda (list comprehension). Boh.. at the moment I don't understand everything but that will come a day.

Comment: Indeed, they are quite different. I've added an example of its use, and I've measured (I've never done it before), that's twice slower than the one with the predicate expressed as a string. In your case, it may be enough though compared to the solution with a manual loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which can do that:

```
function! GetLines(mysearch) range
  let lines = []
  let l:i=a:firstline
  while l:i<=a:lastline
    if matchstr(getline(l:i),a:mysearch) != ''
      call add(lines, l:i)
    endif
    let l:i+=1
  endwhile
  let lines
endfunction
```

You can invoke it by:

```
:N°1,N°2 call GetLines("pattern")
```

Comment: thank you very much for your solution! This seems to work very well but it is not much faster than the solution I wrote in my question.

Comment: No prob at all. ;)